# Is it possible to do this kind of wavy texture procedurally?

Tags: texturing, procedural

[image: Wavy texture]

How should I proceed creating this kind of wavy texture in Blender?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This node setup (be careful on second mapping node scale)
[image: Nodes]

create this wave on plane.
[image: Result]

You can use scale, distortion and detail on noise and musgrave nodes to get desired waves shape. Amplitude frame, multiply node factor change wave scale.

Comment: These days, it's perhaps less confusing to new users to use 'Separate XYZ' and 'Combine XYZ' nodes? I know it doesn't make a big difference, here...

Comment: @RobinBetts yes, this setup more evident https://imgur.com/aw2NzZL and give the same result. And seems to be that nodes XYZ works the same as RGB. Thank you.

Comment: It looks legit, thanks for your help. I forgot to say that I'm rendering with Blender Render though. Do you know how should I modify the node setup to make it work in Blender Render?

Comment: @Memememeyou seems to be change principled shader to something match blender render engine. Just use before nodes as color input.

Comment: RGB and XYZ vectors do behave differently, at least when [coerced into scalar values](https://imgur.com/a/L1rc3n2).  XYZ (1,0,0) is evaluated as 1/3.. RGB(1,0,0) is evaluated as something like 1/4.666.. it seems undefined. Neither value makes much sense to me. I guess the lesson for more complex trees, or groups you intend to re-use is : Never connect a vector output to a scalar input.  Use 'Fac' rather than 'Color' or 'Vector' to get scalar outputs, wherever it's provided. Define your own conversion, if it isn't.

Comment: @RobinBetts thanks for explanation.